# 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download Pdfs using `urllib.request.urlopen` from a page but it returns an error: `'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'`:

```
def get_hansard_data(page_url):
    #Read base_url into Beautiful soup Object
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(page_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    #grab <div class="itemContainer"> that hold links and dates to all hansard pdfs
    hansard_menu = soup.find_all("div","itemContainer")

    #Get all hansards
    #write to a tsv file
    with open("hansards.tsv","a") as f:
        fieldnames = ("date","hansard_url")
        output = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")

        for div in hansard_menu:
            hansard_link = [HANSARD_URL + div.a["href"]]
            hansard_date = div.find("h3", "catItemTitle").string

            #download
            
            with urllib.request.urlopen(hansard_link) as response:
                data = response.read()
                r = open("/Users/Parliament Hansards/"+hansard_date +".txt","wb")
                r.write(data)
                r.close()

            print(hansard_date)
            print(hansard_link)
            output.writerow([hansard_date,hansard_link])
        print ("Done Writing File")
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace. The code you posted doesn't include a call to timeout so its hard to locate

Comment: version: Python 3.4. Error occurs in this line: with urllib.request.urlopen(hansard_link) as response:

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but might still be helpful to someone else (if not for topic starter). I found the solution by solving the same problem.

The problem was that `page_url` (in your case) was a list, rather than a string. The reason for that is mos likely that `page_url` comes from `argparse.parse_args()` (at least it was so in my case).
Doing `page_url[0]` should work but it is not nice to do that inside the `def get_hansard_data(page_url)` function. Better would be to check the type of the parameter and return an appropriate error to the function caller, if the type does not match.

The type of an argument could be checked by calling `type(page_url)` and comparing the result like for example: `typen("") == type(page_url)`. I am sure there might be more elegant way to do that, but it is out of the scope of this particular question.