# Python list object has no attribute error

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a website scraper to get links from subreddits, which I can then pass to another class later on for automatic download of images from imagur.

In this code snippet, I am just trying to read the subreddit and scrape any imagur htmls from hrefs, but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Any idea as to why this might be happening? Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import sys
from urlparse import urljoin

def get_category_links(base_url):
    url = base_url
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    posts = soup('a',{'class':'title may-blank loggedin outbound'})
    #get the links with the class "title may-blank "
    #which is how reddit defines posts
    for post in posts:
        print post.contents[0]
        #print the post's title

        if post['href'][:4] =='http':
            print post['href']
        else:
            print urljoin(url,post['href'])
        #print the url.  
        #if the url is a relative url,
        #print the absolute url.   


get_category_links(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Either post the full traceback or mention the line number.

Comment: Did you use `.read()` on urlopen?

Comment: Please post the full error message including traceback. That error isn't directly caused by your code, it's coming from one of the libraries you're using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128329/list-object-has-no-attribute-timeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at how you call the function:

```
get_category_links(sys.argv)
```

[`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) here is *a list of script arguments* where the first item is the script name itself. This means that your `base_url` argument value is a list which leads to failing `urlopen`:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> urlopen(["I am", "a list"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           │           │    │     └ <object object at 0x105e2c120>
           │           │    └ None
           │           └ ['I am', 'a list']
           └ <urllib2.OpenerDirector instance at 0x105edc638>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
    │             └ <object object at 0x105e2c120>
    └ ['I am', 'a list']
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

You meant to get the second argument from `sys.argv` and pass it to `get_category_links`:

```
get_category_links(sys.argv[1])
```

---

It's interesting though, how cryptic and difficult to understand the error in this case is. This is coming from the way the ["url opener" works in Python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/urllib2.py#L411). If, the `url` value (the first argument) is not a string, it assumes it is a `Request` instance and tries to set a `timeout` value on it:

```
def open(self, fullurl, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
    # accept a URL or a Request object
    if isinstance(fullurl, basestring):
        req = Request(fullurl, data)
    else:
        req = fullurl
        if data is not None:
            req.add_data(data)

    req.timeout = timeout  # <-- FAILS HERE
```

Note that the [behavior have not actually changed in the latest stable 3.6 as well](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/urllib/request.py#L508-L517).

Comment: Can you share how to pretty-print traceback like yours in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @zhenguoli sure, this is the [`better-exceptions`](https://github.com/Qix-/better-exceptions) project, pretty cool and handy. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are so kind.