# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, attributeerror

I dont know why the code is giving error

```
  File "<ipython-input-68-1efe37b7d511>", line 1, in <module>
    sourceData = urllib.request.urlopen(url_list[0])

  File "C:\Users\Sajid Hasan Sifat\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Users\Sajid Hasan Sifat\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 516, in open
    req.timeout = timeout

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

My Code

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse 
import re
import nltk
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame


nltk.download('stopwords')
import heapq

listofurls = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Sajid Hasan Sifat/Desktop/global one/GO-url.csv") 
urls = DataFrame(listofurls, columns = ['urls'])
url_list = urls.values.tolist()
print(url_list[0])

req = urllib.request.Request(url_list[0])    
print(req) 
sourceData = urllib.request.urlopen(url_list[0]) 

source = sourceData.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source)
```

Comment: What is the output for this? ```print(url_list[0])```

Comment: This is already asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139008/11094041)